# Bluehost (or PHP Script) Issue With Cookies

Tags: php, apache, cookies, bluehost

I've got the weirdest problem with Cookies. I've written some PHP script that uses tokens to identify the visitor so that "he/she" can use the website correctly.

The Token system is working perfectly on the local development machine (windoze+ZendApache) and doesn't work on the production server, which is on Bluehost.

I use "/" for path and "mydomain.com" for the domain when setting the cookie with an expiry of 60 days. I can see the cookies on the browser correctly and I can confirm that the values are set correctly when compared to the values in the database.

Every time the page gets refreshed the server doesn't get the cookie and creates a new token and sends it back to the browser and is creating a new record in the database again. The new cookie matches the latest record again, but next time I refresh, same thing all over again. Can't maintain the token, so navigating the site is impossible.

Any idea why this is happening? Is it possible that I've missed some setting?

I've tested it on latest Firefox, Opera, Safari and Chrome.

Thanks.

EDIT:

It is a PHP & Bluehost related issue, I was storing 3, 40-character strings on the value of the cookie in serialized format. The unserialize() function wasn't executing for some reason on Bluehost but was running fine on my dev machine. So I changed the stored value to 40chars.40chars.40chars and exploded the value with the delimiter "." to get the 3 strings.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use

```
.mydomain.com
```

instead of

```
mydomain.com
```

for example:

```
setcookie("MyCookie", $value, time()+60*24*3600, "/", ".mydomain.com", 1);
```

Comment: It adds the . (dot) in front by itself. I thought of that and tried it but the issue remains. It appears that the browser isn't sending the cookie with the token data. If I print_r the $_REQUEST I can see all other cookies except the one that is holding the token values.

Comment: give us some code examples please. how do you get/set the cookie you mentioned? how do you define the token? etc.

Comment: Well, I just found out that bluehost doesn't like the unserialize() function very much. I was storing the 3 values in the token cookie serialized but could get those values on the next refresh. I'm rewriting the token system script to use implode() and explode() to set and get the cookie data. Thank you tho for taking the time to answer. ;)